# Amazon SP-API Rate Limit

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rate-limiting, aws-api-gateway

anyone familiar with the rate limit for [Orders API](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/orders-api/ordersV0.md)

am calling the following EndPoint `orders/v0/orders/{}/buyerInfo`

[image]

It's should be 1 request per second ? and what the meaning of `Burst 1` here? i don't understand it at all.

I've already tried to sleep 1 second between each request but i keep getting the following error.

```
You exceeded your quota for the requested resource.
```

but if i kept increment the sleep between requests. the API sometimes answer and sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

The Burst setting and Rate setting work together to control how many requests can be processed by your API.
Let's assume you set the throttle to Rate = 100 (requests per second) and the Burst = 50 (requests). With those settings if 100 concurrent requests are sent at the exact same millisecond only 50 would be processed due to the burst setting, the remaining 50 requests would get a 429 Too Many Requests response. Assuming the first 50 requests completed in 100ms each, your client could then retry the remaining 50 requests.